# Adding properties to created Redux Store in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I'm having issues adding a property when I create a new Redux Store in Typescript:

```
const bindMiddleware = middleware => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}

function configureStore (initialState = exampleInitialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    bindMiddleware([sagaMiddleware])
  )

  store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

  return store
}

export default configureStore
```

with the following error message:

```
27:9 Property 'sagaTask' does not exist on type 'Store<{ error: any; count: number; lastUpdate: number; light: boolean; placeholderData: any; } | { lastUpdate: any; light: boolean; count: number; error: boolean; placeholderData: any; }, any>'.
    25 |   )
    26 | 
  > 27 |   store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
       |         ^
    28 | 
    29 |   return store
    30 | }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The idea of `TypeScript` is that you know at compile time what properties each Object will have, so you have to define the properties before you use them. The `store` already has a TypeScript definition somewhere, definition which doesn't mention anything about `sagaTask`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@types/
| - redux.d.ts
src/
| ...
| ... store.ts
```

in `redux.d.ts`

```
import * as Redux from "redux"

declare module "redux" {
  export interface Store {
    sagaTask: ... // provide the types for `store.sagaTask` here 
  }
}
```

in `store.ts`

```
const store = createStore(...)
store.sagaTask = ...
```

this is known as [declaration merging / module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

You need to also setup your `tsconfig.json` to read types from this `@types` dir. Add `"typeRoots": [ "./@types", "./node_modules/@types" ]` to this file (note: these are relative to your `baseDir`, so modify accordingly.

Also note that *you're creating a contract between your types and the code you write*. If you fail to setup your middleware properly, `sagaTask` will be `Required` in types but `undefined` in reality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Saga so I'm not sure about best practices or what ramifications this approach might have, but the issue is that the Store type doesn't have a sagaTask, so TypeScript won't let this happen. The easiest way that I can see to solve this is to extend Store and add a sagaTask field, then copy the old store to a new object of the extended type.

The downside to this is that you could easily run into a situation where a function is expecting an object with a Store type, so it won't accept this new object.

Are you sure this needs to be a property of the store, or can you just run sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)?