# Next.js: why use (store as sagaStore).sagaTask... and toPromise() in redux-saga with next-redux-wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

What's the need of defining this statement like this in next-redux-wrapper makeStore: `(store as SagaStore).sagaTask`, instead of simply declaring `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);`.

```
export const makeStore = (context) => {
    ...
    (store as SagaStore).sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    return store; };
```

Also, in individual pages, why do I need to declare this statement: `await store.sagaTask.toPromise()`:

```
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {
 ...
await store.sagaTask.toPromise()
})
```

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64165083/10431574